# How to mock a File as a prop in jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I'm busy getting into unit testing with React, Jest and Enzyme.

I've got a component that takes a PDF `File` as a prop, see this interface:

```
interface IProps {
  file: File;
}
```

I'm trying to do a straight up basic test just to make sure the component renders without crashing using it's required props (i.e. the `File`).

Here's my test case:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  const props = {
    file: /* How do I mock this file? */
  };

  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
  });
});
```

How do I mock a `File` for the `file` prop?

Comment: Hi maybe this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488985/how-to-mock-file-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Mock Functions https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    const props = {
    file: jest.fn()
};

it('renders without crashing', () => {
    mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
 });
});
```