# Dropzone js data for addFile() method

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I can't figure out - what data should be passed to `Dropzone.addFile()` to add already uploaded file to dropzone list.

now I have:

```
$.each(attachments[drop.data('name')], function (index, item) {
    let mock = {
        name: item.original_name,
        size: item.size,
        dataUrl: item.relative_url,
        type: item.mime_type
    };
    drop[0].dropzone.addFile(mock);
});
```

and have following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
at Dropzone.createThumbnail (dropzone-amd-module.js:2025)
at Dropzone._processThumbnailQueue (dropzone-amd-module.js:1922)
at dropzone-amd-module.js:1907

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.
at Dropzone._uploadData (dropzone-amd-module.js:2514)
at dropzone-amd-module.js:2381
at dropzone-amd-module.js:2535
at Dropzone.transformFile (dropzone-amd-module.js:689)
at _loop (dropzone-amd-module.js:2532)
at Dropzone._transformFiles (dropzone-amd-module.js:2541)
at Dropzone.uploadFiles (dropzone-amd-module.js:2293)
at Dropzone.processFiles (dropzone-amd-module.js:2198)
at Dropzone.processFile (dropzone-amd-module.js:2166)
at Dropzone.processQueue (dropzone-amd-module.js:2155)
```

What I missed in my `mock` array to make this thing work propertly?

Comment: @OlegShaktov did you solve it ?

Comment: @AabirHussain Yep, but in different maner, I also made a lot of support logic to recognize newly added files and availability to delete already uploaded files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used some code to show previously uploaded images. I hope this could help you.

```
/**
 * Display images, modify this function according to your needs
 */
function displayOldImage() {
 const data = JSON.parse($('#oldImages').val());
 let myDropzone = this;
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    const mockFile = {name: value.name, size: value.size};
    myDropzone.files[key] = value.name;
    myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
    myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, value.url);
       mockFile.previewElement.classList.add('dz-success');
       mockFile.previewElement.classList.add('dz-complete');
    });
 }

var dropzoneUploader = new Dropzone("div#dropzone-file-input", {
     url: JS_BASE_URL + 'gallery/photo/add-file',
     parallelUploads: 10,
     addRemoveLinks: true,
     maxFiles: 25,
     maxFilesize: 2,
     dictDefaultMessage: message,
     acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png',
     preventDuplicates: true,
     init: displayOldImage, //here is the function call for your requirements
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

From the Github project, you can see the `addFile` implementation: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/08b9e0a763b54a685404dea523a9c54242fbe1b9/dist/dropzone.js#L1812

It doesn't give any documentation but if you check inside this function they are using predefined properties (specifically the size property) that make me think of the `Blob` javascript object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

**EDIT: The error is also suggesting you using the Blob type so the prediction was correct hahaha**

**EDIT2: The `File` Javascript object is inheriting from the `Blob` one, so you may also use the `File` type**

Comment: A can't do this anyway, I made what I want with another approach.

Comment: Check this before downvoting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488985/how-to-mock-file-in-javascript

Comment: @OlegShakhov Then post it as an aswer here for the community ?